# Xamarin.Forms MergedDictionaries

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have created few XAML styles and added them all into App.xaml.cs as MergedDictionaries

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"  
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Axon.Mobile.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDictionaries/Colors.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDictionaries/GlobalStylesDictionary.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDictionaries/KeyStylesDictionary.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDictionaries/ReceptionStylesDictionary.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDictionaries/PutAwayStylesDictionary.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDictionaries/ViewModelLocatorDictionary.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

This soolution is working when I use style defined in any dictionary as StatisResouce i.e:

```
<Label TextColor="{StaticResource Test1}"/>
```

However I would like to create dynamic resources and in that case I need to replace the styles in C#. The problem is that

> Application.Current.Resources

contains these 6 another dictionaries as MergedDictionary property. All of given dictionaries are empty.

Why can't I get the defined styles in C#?

Answer (score 4):

That's strange but I've noticed  that we can only access resources located in MergedDictionaries using the TryGetValue method for the moment:

```
 if (Application.Current.Resources.TryGetValue("StyleResourceKey", out var objectStyle))
 {
     var style = (Style)objectStyle;

     //Edit your style
 }
```

Comment: Is this a bug in Xamarin? It still the case now with XF 5